# NVIDIA codec compression time

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, hevc

I'm working with the NVIDIA video codec to encode a YUV video to the HEVC format. The problem is that I want to know the time it takes to perform the encoding and I can not find the way.

Other codecs supported by FFMPEG such as x265 or hevc_qsv show the encoding time at the end of the process, but in the case of the NVIDIA codec no. Does anyone know of any command or method that allows to show this information?

Comment: How are you using the codec? Can you just wrap the library/executable calls in a timer?

Comment: I use it in the following way. Here is an example: ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s:v 1920x1080 -r 25 -i ParkScene_240F_1920x1080_24Hz_P420.yuv -rc constqp -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 22 -psnr pruebaa.hevc

Comment: @mt94 `time ffmpeg ...` on Linux

Comment: or `... -psnr pruebaa.hevc -benchmark` to enable the inbuilt timer.